# UI in n-tier c#

Tags: n-tier-architecture

Good day,

I am having trouble with using n-tier architecture. 
here's my problem

I want to create a simple n-tier web based application i already added the DAL which comes from our previous project together with the BAL. now i added a project just to hold my my UI. i want to reuse the DAL and the BAL from our previous project. when i add the existing project (both the DAL and BAL) to my web application project, everything run smoothly. i already reference their dll respectively.

I already created the database path on my webconfig and use that path in my application. when i create a method that will extract the record of of my table, in my UI. there's no problem but when i generate my the method that was created in UI. the generated method was not in the BAL project but it is generated in BAL metadata. is there any problem with my UI project?

thanks

Comment: You define what exactly is the problem and show some example code.